# jQuery hover - mouseout not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following script here...  It works when I mouseover the item...  but when the mouse leaves, it doesn't hide anything.  In fact, it just seems like an endless loop.  Help please! :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
    $(".hover").hover(
      function () {
         $('.hide').hide();
        var clss = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.pop_'+clss+'').show('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $('.hide').hide('slow');
      }
    );


});
</script>
```

Comment: what are you hiding/showing, can you add some html to the question?

Comment: First you're hiding it, then you're hiding it slower? How's that supposed to work ?

Comment: Thank you for all the replies.  Here is an example:  [http://deliversocial.com/hover/](http://deliversocial.com/hover/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fly in boxes are gaining focus as soon as they come in, which is triggering the mouseleave function you implemented and they disappear.  In order to get the functionality you want you need either:

1. Bind the mouseleave to the .hide divs that are appearing
2. Make it so the new divs don't overlap the .hover elements

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with jQuery .bind usage.  Any chance you could help with that?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to move the $(".hover").mouseleave part to another element.  Try replacing .hover with .hide and see what happens.